# why div not working in while loop in php

Tags: php, css

```
    <!-- BLOG CONTENT
============================================= -->
<div class="container">
    <div class="row" id="primary">
       <main id="content" class="col-sm-8 role="main>
```

```
<?php 

$query = "SELECT * FROM posts";
$start_posts_query = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($start_posts_query)){
    $post_title = $row['title'];
    $post_author = $row['author'];
    $post_date = $row['date'];
    $post_image = $row['image'];
    $post_content = $row['content'];
    $post_tags = $row['tags'];

?>
```

HTML

```
      <header>
                   <h3><a href="post.html"><?php echo $post_title; ?></a></h3>
                   <div class="post-details">
                    <i class="fa fa-user"></i>  
                    <?php echo $post_author; ?> 

                    <i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i>  
                    <time><?php echo $post_date; ?></time>

                    <i class="fa fa-folder"></i>  
                    <a href="">Tutorials</a>, <a href="">Coding</a>

                    <i class="fa fa-tags"></i>  
                    Tagged <a href=""><?php echo $post_tags; ?></a>
```

> This bellow comment bubble div i added in while loop but its displaying only on first post in blog not others.

```
                    <div class="post-comments-badge">
                      <a href=""><i class="fa fa-comments"></i> 168</a>  
                    </div><!-- post-comments-badge -->
```

> So please suggest me how can i show this comment bubble on each post in while loop.

```
                   </div><!-- post-detail -->
               </header>
               <div class="post-image">
                   <img src="assets/img/learn-php.jpg" alt="Heri image">
               </div><!-- post-image -->
               <div class="post-excerpt">
                  <p><?php echo $post_content; ?><a href="post.html">continue reaing &raquo;</a></p> 



               </div><!-- post-excerpt -->
           </article><!-- post -->
           </main><!-- content -->
```

Comment: What problem you face to do that??? You may have the comment table, query and fetch and than show them here like you do for post.

Comment: Better would be to post entire code with that HTML and PHP part. It would be easier to read.

Comment: Have you ended while loop?

Comment: <?php } ?>

yes i ended the loop before this </div><!-- post-excerpt -->

Answer (score 0):

please to complete your double quote for this code:

```
<main id="content" class="col-sm-8 role="main>
```

to be:

```
<main id="content" class="col-sm-8" role="main">
```

Answer (score 0):

How about we change some of your style code,

Start from this until

```
    <!-- BLOG CONTENT
============================================= -->
<div class="container">
    <div class="row" id="primary">
           <article class="post">
           <header>

           <?php

            $query = "SELECT * FROM posts";
            $start_posts_query = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($start_posts_query)){
                echo "<h3><a href='post.html'>".$contest['title']."</a></h3>";
                echo "<div class='post-details'>";
                echo "<i class='fa fa-user'></i>";
                echo .$contest['author'];
                echo "div";

            }

            ?>

            </header>
            </article>
        </div>
    </div>
```